# i want .properties file to be loaded part by part during lifetime of a progress bar?

Tags: java

my .properties file is :

```
#Properties file: Parameters for TP1
#Thu Feb 20 20:44:15 PST 2014
TP1.Polarization=V
TP1.SatelliteFrequency=11480
TP1.SymbolRate=28.8
#Properties file: Parameters for TP2
#Thu Feb 20 20:44:15 PST 2014
TP2.SymbolRate=30
TP2.SatelliteFrequency=11520
TP2.Polarization=V
#Properties file: Parameters for TP3
#Thu Feb 20 20:44:15 PST 2014
TP3.Polarization=V
TP3.SymbolRate=30
TP3.SatelliteFrequency=11560
#Properties file: Parameters for TP4
#Thu Feb 20 20:44:15 PST 2014
TP4.Polarization=H
TP4.SatelliteFrequency=11600
TP4.SymbolRate=30
#Properties file: Parameters for TP5
#Thu Feb 20 20:44:15 PST 2014
TP5.SatelliteFrequency=11600
TP5.Polarization=V
TP5.SymbolRate=30
```

and so on upto 11 TP.

code for properties file reader is:

```
public class PropertyFilesReader {
public void AutoTPparam() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    //Reading properties file in Java example
    Properties props1 = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/NOC/workspace/Helloworld/src/resources/user.properties");

    //loading properties from properties file
    props1.load(fis);
    //reading property

    String SatFreq1 = props1.getProperty("TP1.SatelliteFrequency");
    String SR1 = props1.getProperty("TP1.SymbolRate");
    String Polarization1 = props1.getProperty("TP1.Polarization");

    String SatFreq2 = props1.getProperty("TP2.SatelliteFrequency");
    String SR2 = props1.getProperty("TP2.SymbolRate");
    String Polarization2 = props1.getProperty("TP2.Polarization");

    String SatFreq3 = props1.getProperty("TP3.SatelliteFrequency");
    String SR3 = props1.getProperty("TP3.SymbolRate");
    String Polarization3 = props1.getProperty("TP3.Polarization");

    String SatFreq4 = props1.getProperty("TP4.SatelliteFrequency");
    String SR4 = props1.getProperty("TP4.SymbolRate");
    String Polarization4 = props1.getProperty("TP4.Polarization");

    String SatFreq5 = props1.getProperty("TP5.SatelliteFrequency");
    String SR5 = props1.getProperty("TP5.SymbolRate");
    String Polarization5 = props1.getProperty("TP5.Polarization");
}
}
```

now what will be the coding for loading this property file within a progress bar..??
I want that the progress bar loads in five parts for 5 TP parameters ... with progress shown in percentage....

Comment: Check [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)

Comment: This depends a lot on the application type (web, rich client, mobile app, etc) and on the UI framwework you are using. An other question is whether you want the progress bar to visualize the raeding of the actual file form the the file system or the evaluation of the properties.

Comment: @BetaRide :i am using Swing in Eclipse IDE.yes i want the progress bar to load actual properties from properties file,before launching the original application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer variable as part of the property name.

```
JProgressBar bar;
Properties props1;
int step;
String sr;
// (...)
bar.setMaximum(5); // 5 = fully done
// (...)
   step = bar.getValue();
   sr = props1.getProperty("TP"+step+".SymbolRate");
```

and so on.

Comment: i have main method in different class, and progress bar code is also there only.. that is, i am creating an object of PropertyFilesReader class and invoking the method AutoTPparam() with this object in different class file,where main method lies...and i want to use progress bar there...so, how can i use above cited technique of urs...